# How did the Dursley family get home from the shack?

Tags: harry-potter

Harry and Hagrid leave the Dursley family on the shack on the rock and take the only boat.

This is a good days drive from their home.

Harry and Hagrid have a day out in London and Hagrid drops Harry at Paddington* with the assumption that he is going back home.

**How were the Durslies meant to get back in time?** Has this ever been discussed?

* Most trains to Surrey leave from Victoria or Waterloo, JKR often seems to get London stations mixed up

Comment: Yes it is. Thanks.

Comment: Harry had a key. Problem solved.